# Ruby string representation

Tags: ruby, string, encoding

i have in database a string like \303\255 which represents í .

How can i convert that 8 chars representation in í ?

I could replace them all, but isn't there any other way ?

Comment: Do you mean you have the string: `str = "\"\\303\\255\""` (i.e. the slashes really *are* in the string?). You'll have to extract them and `Array#pack` them into real characters if they are.

Comment: Do you have the problem with Ruby 1.8.x or Ruby 1.9.x? In 1.9.x, the solution of @JonasElfström should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the problem really is as you describe, and not just a misunderstanding.

I battled with this.  It's not pretty.  This parses the string and uses `pack` to pack down the relevant bytes.

```
"foo \\303\\255 bar".gsub(/(\\\d{3})+/) do |match|
  match[1..-1].split("\\").map{ |octet| octet.to_i(8) }.pack("c*")
end.force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

The much shorter version uses `eval`, but it's always worth trying to avoid `eval` if you can, since it has huge security risks if used incorrectly.  Given that we're validating the format of what we're `eval`'ing here, I'll go ahead and say it's probably safe to do this:

```
"foo \\303\\255 bar".gsub(/(\\\d{3})+/) { |m| eval('"' + m + '"') }
```

Comment: The eval is working! Will check why the first os not working... Thanks a lot man! :D

Comment: Make sure you only eval the bits of the string you know are safe, otherwise (if you could find yourself in a mess). My code is ok, but `eval`'ing the entire string, while it would likely work, would be dangerous.

Comment: This is internal and private data transformation so it's ok to use eval on this, but thanks for the warning!

Answer (score 1):

It's not really 8 characters in the string, it's 2 bytes. I'm not sure where you want \303\255 to show up as í but if you put

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

in the top of your .rb-file Ruby will use UTF-8.

If you are using Ruby on Rails you can try to add the following two lines to config/environment.rb

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```